# How do I fix the error that django keeps giving me when I try to click to update my form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have tried many different ways, including class based views to make a user able to edit the form they completed. I get the same error no matter what I try and can't get to the bottom of it. I tried to post just enough code below so it is readable. Here are the errors:

Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:

Reverse for 'update' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['update/(?P[^/]+)/$']

Exception Location:     /Users/name/Desktop/Django/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 677

### In template /Users/name/Desktop/Django/dv_project/myapp/templates/base.html, error at line 12

```
models.py

class StepOne(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    title = "STEP 1: Safety during a violent incident"
    box1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    box2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    box3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    box4 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    box5 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    box6 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title class StepOne(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    title = "STEP 1: Safety during a violent incident"
    box1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    box2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    box3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    box4 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    box5 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    box6 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

```
forms.py

class StepOneForm(forms.ModelForm):
    box1 = forms.CharField()

    class Meta: 
        model = StepOne  #which model we want to use as a model for our model form
        fields= ("box1","box2","box3", "box4", "box5", "box6")
```

```
views.py

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import StepOneForm
from .models import StepOne, CreateUserForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def update(request, id):                                         
    data = get_object_or_404(StepOne, id=id)
    form = StepOneForm(instance=data)                                                               

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = StepOneForm(request.POST, instance=data)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect ('user-homepage')
    context = {
        "form":form,
        "data": data
    }
    return render(request, 'shell_test', context)



def loginPage(request):

    if request.method == "POST": #The user entered the info and logged in.
        username = request.POST.get('username') #this is sent from the front end through the login.html.
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        try:
            user= User.objects.get(username=username)
        except:
            messages.error(request, "User does not exist.")
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password) #if get was successful authenticate user.
        if user is not None: #if we got a user
            login(request, user) #will add the session in the database and browser.
            return redirect('user-homepage')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Username or password does not exist.")
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'registration/login_registration.html', context)


def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request) # deletes the token/user session
    return redirect('welcome')

@login_required(login_url='login_user')
def Step1_Form_Completion(request):
    """Generates link for user to fill out form"""
    form = StepOneForm                #Assign the form to the variable in the function.
    if request.method == 'POST':     # if method or form is requested then POST or send data to this function. If someone is loggded in . . 
        try:
            form = StepOneForm(request.POST) #the method is form and it is to be posted.
            if form.is_valid():             #if the form is django's definiton for 'valid' then save it and redirect the user home.
                form.instance.user= request.user
                form.save()
                return redirect('user-homepage')
        except:
            messages.success(request, 'Cannot resubmit. Please use "edit" instead.')
            return redirect('user-homepage')

    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form':form} ) # return  this function to the form.html page and let it use form as s variable and call it's attributes (form.box1)


@login_required(login_url='login_user')  #sends user back to login page if they try to go to a view form.
def Step1_Form_View(request):
    """View for user to see completed form"""
    step1 = StepOne.objects.filter(user=request.user) #user can only view there form. request user and filter the objects/forms for there step oneform.
    return render(request,'form_view.html',{'step1': step1})



def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def register_user(request):
    form = UserCreationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST': #if someone has filled out a form do something.
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            password2 = form.cleaned_data['password2']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password) #authenticate user
            login(request, user)  #log user in
            messages.success(request, 'Registration Successful')
            return redirect('user-homepage')
        else:
            messages.success(request, 'Already Registered, please log in.')
    return render(request, 'registration/register_user.html', {'form': form} )



def shellTesting(request):
    thing = StepOne.objects.get(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'shell_test.html', {'thing': thing})

def welcome(request):
    return render(request, 'welcome.html')


def base(request):
    return render(request, 'base.html')
```

```
urls.py

path('update/<str:id>/', views.update, name='update'),
```

```
index.html 

<!-- This is the page that the link to editable the form is located, I only put the code for the button to make it shorter -->

      <a href="{% url 'update' data.id  %}">Edit</a>
```

```
forms.html

{% block content %}


</head>
<body>


        <form method='post'>
            {% csrf_token %}
        
        STEP 1: Safety during a violent incident. I will not always be able to avoid violent incidents. In order to increase safety I may use a variety of strategies.
        I can use some of the following strategies:
        <p>
        A. If I decide to leave, I will {{ form.box1 }}. (Practice how to get out safely. What doors, windows, elevators, stairwells, or fire escapes would you use?)
        <p>
        B. I can keep my purse and car keys ready and put them (location) {{ form.box2 }} in order to leave quickly.
        </p>
        <p>
        C. I can tell {{ form.box3  }} about the violence and request that she or he call the police if she or he hears suspicious noises coming from my house.
        </p>
        <p>
        D. I can teach my children how to use the telephone to contact the police, the fire department, and 911. E. I will use {{ form.box4 }} as my code with my children or my
        friends so they can call for help.
        </p>
        <p>
        F. If I have to leave my home, I will go to {{ form.box5  }}. (Decide this even if you don’t think there will be a next time.)
        <p>
        G. I can also teach some of these strategies to some or all of my children.
        </p>
        <p>
        H. When I expect we’re going to have an argument, I’ll try to move to a place that is low risk, such as {{ form.box6 }}. (Try to avoid arguments in the bathroom, garage, kitchen, near weapons, or in rooms without access to an outside door.)
        </p>
        <p>
        I. I will use my judgment and intuition. If the situation is very serious, I can give my partner what he/she wants to calm him/her down.
        </p>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>


</body>
</html>

{% endblock content %}
```

```
base.html
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'website/style.css' %}">

    <!-- The line and href below are really important it formats the navbar and makes the "container" gutter work. -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">



    <title>DV_Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      {% include 'navbar.html' %}
      <br/>
        <div class="container"> <!--creates a gutter for content on homepage, this is good.-->

      {% if messages %}
      <ul class="messages">
          {% for message in messages %}
          <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
          <strong>{{message}}</strong> <!-- could write message here -->
         <!-- <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button> -->
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
      </ul>
      {% endif %}

       {% block content %}
     {% endblock %}
      </div>
  </body>


</html>
```

```
index.html

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<!--Row -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-auto">
      Step 1: A Violent Incident
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-auto">
        <a href="{%  url 'step1'  %}">Form</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-auto">
        <a href="{% url 'form_view'  %}">View</a>
    </div>


    <div class="col-sm-auto">
      <a href="{% url 'update'  data.id %}">Edit</a>
    </div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

```
welcome.html

{% load static %}

{% include 'navbar.html' %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'website/style.css' %}">

    <!-- The line and href below are really important it formats the navbar and makes the "container" gutter work. -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">



  </head>
  <body>

      <br/>
        <div class="container"> <!--creates a gutter for content on homepage, this is good.-->
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
        <h3>Please register below or log in above.</h3>
        <h7>This website has security features built-in. However, by creating account you are 
            accepting responsbility for how it is used and who has access to it through your devices.</h7><p>


        <p><p><a href="{%  url 'register_user'  %}">Register Here!</a></p>
      </div>

      <div>

       {% block content %}
     {% endblock %}
      </div>
  </body>


</html>
```

```
<html>
    
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <style>
        body,
        html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
            background: purple !important;
        }
        .user_card {
            width: 350px;
            margin-top: auto;
            margin-bottom: auto;
            background: grey;
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            padding: 10px;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
            border-radius: 5px;

        }

        .form_container {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        #form-title{
            color: purple;
            
        }

        .login_btn {
            width: 100%;
            background: purple !important;
            color: white !important;
        }
        .login_btn:focus {
            box-shadow: none !important;
            outline: 0px !important;
        }
        .login_container {
            padding: 0 2rem;
        }
        .input-group-text {
            background: purple !important;
            color: white !important;
            border: 0 !important;
            border-radius: 0.25rem 0 0 0.25rem !important;
        }
        .input_user,
        .input_pass:focus {
            box-shadow: none !important;
            outline: 0px !important;
        }

        #messages{
            background-color: grey;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
            <div class="user_card">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">


                    <h3 id="form-title">LOGIN</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center form_container">
                    <form method="POST" action="">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            {{form.username}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                            </div>
                                {{form.password1}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                            </div>
                                {{form.password2}}
                        </div>

                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 login_container">
                                <input class="btn login_btn" type="submit" value="Login">
                            </div>
                    </form>

                </div>
    
            
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <script>
                        /* Because i didnt set placeholder values in forms.py they will be set here using vanilla Javascript
        //We start indexing at one because CSRF_token is considered and input field 
         */

        //Query All input fields - this javascript just tells the code where to put the 'string'
        var form_fields = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
        form_fields[1].placeholder='Username..';
        form_fields[2].placeholder='Enter password...';
        form_fields[3].placeholder='Re-enter Password...';


        for (var field in form_fields){ 
            form_fields[field].className += ' form-control'
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">

                        <!-- Name of NavBar --> 
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'welcome' %}"><h4> DV Plan</h4></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-10">


                      <!-- Link 1 --> 

          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="{% url 'welcome' %}">Homepage</a>


          <!-- Only Logged in User can see forms -->
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="{% url 'user-homepage' %}">{{user}}'s Profile</a>
        {% else %}
        {% endif %}

        <!-- Logged in user can see logout button-->
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <a class="nav-link"  href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
        {% else %}
        <a class="nav-link"  href="{% url 'login_user' %}">Login</a>
        {% endif %}


                    <!-- Dropdown Items 
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li> -->



      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex" role="search">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

```
form_view.html
{% include 'navbar.html' %}

    <!-- The line and href below are really important it formats the navbar and makes the "container" gutter work. -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
{% if step1 %}
 <h1>Your Step 1 Plan</h1>

 <tr>
     {% for st in step1 %}


    <p>
    A. If I decide to leave, I will <b>{{ st.box1}}</b>. (Practice how to get out safely. What doors, windows, elevators, stairwells, or fire escapes would you use?)
    <p>
    B. I can keep my purse and car keys ready and put them (location) <b>{{ st.box2 }}</b> in order to leave quickly.
    </p>
    <p>
    C. I can tell <b>{{ st.box3  }}</b> about the violence and request that she or he call the police if she or he hears suspicious noises coming from my house.
    </p>
    <p>
    D. I can teach my children how to use the telephone to contact the police, the fire department, and 911. E. I will use </b>{{ st.box4 }}</b> as my code with my children or my
    friends so they can call for help.
    </p>
    <p>
    F. If I have to leave my home, I will go to <b>{{st.box5}}</b>. (Decide this even if you don’t think there will be a next time.)
    <p>
    G. I can also teach some of these strategies to some or all of my children.
    </p>
    <p>
    H. When I expect we’re going to have an argument, I’ll try to move to a place that is low risk, such as <b>{{ st.box6 }}</b>. (Try to avoid arguments in the bathroom, garage, kitchen, near weapons, or in rooms without access to an outside door.)
    </p>
    <p>
    I. I will use my judgment and intuition. If the situation is very serious, I can give my partner what he/she wants to calm him/her down.
    </p>


     {% endfor %}
{% else %}
 <h1>No Data</h1>
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

```
settings.html

"""
Django settings for dv_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'zg&-*6rqdiqyu4fnq26-w%4)uw@nvlx@9o85)+&z(aaqxy^=_n'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp.apps.MyappConfig',
]



MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'dv_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'dv_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK="bootstrap4"

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'welcome'

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "welcome"
```

Comment: How do you pass the context to view that is using `index.html` template?

Comment: I pass form.html into the return request because I am trying to edit that form. The index.html is just to have the link to the editable form.

Comment: please provide [mre]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't pass the `data` in any context, then you cannot expect it to be rendered anyhow in the template. It does not take it from view's variables.

If you want data to be in template, then add it to the context:

```
context = {"form": form, "data": data}
return render(request, 'form.html', context)
```

or in ANY view, that you want to include `{% url 'update' data.id  %}`:

```
def index(request):
    data = ...
    context = {"data": data}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

PS don't put code in comments. Add it to your Question.

Comment: Hmm, still not working. I can't find out how to get the idea of my form and pass it to be edited. So there is def something wrong with how I am passing it into my functions. I found a similar questions but nobody has found an answer to it either:  https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/hzh1u9/passing_object_id_to_views_function/

Comment: Ok, now I think you don't really understand how views work and there is main problem, the guy from reddit has a working answer in the link you have provided. You want to add a link to update view for a specific object, but you don't have such object in the `index` view. It supposed to be some main, generic view, and you cannot pass specific object. To get such object you need to have the `id` in the url, but in `index` you don't pass the `id` in the url (you didn't provide it, but I assume it's something like "localhost:8000/index", so view has no `id` to operate with.

Comment: Study this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/views/ , and then it should be clearer. You have answers here, but you don't understand the process yet.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the trick was learning the phrase, "passing the query string" After reading about this on Google I figured it out.

I had to filter for forms in my view. Then, have my .html code filter the request.user's form and added this to {% "url-name" Form.id %} so it passed the form.id into the urls.py, then from there I passed it into my view. So it was like a full circle, starting with the .html document parsing for the right form through the request.user variable. Here is a sample:

```
views.py 

def form_one_page(request):
form = StepOne.objects.filter(user=request.user)
context = { 'form': form,
}
return render(request, 'form_one_page.html', context)
```

@login_required
def editpost(request, step_one):
"""Form1 Edit post function"""
step1 = StepOne.objects.filter(user=request.user.id) #Gets user id and finds if they have a StepOne form.
step_one = StepOne.objects.get(pk=step_one) #Gets passed the form id by logged in user. See function form_one_page to see how it's passing query string.
form = StepOneForm(instance=step_one)
if request.method == 'POST':
form = StepOneForm(request.POST, instance=step_one)
if form.is_valid():
form.save()
return redirect('user-homepage')
return render(request,'update_form.html', {"form": form, "step1": step1})

```
    user-homepage.html 
  <tbody>
        <td><div class="span12" style="text-align:center">
          {% for f in form1 %}
          <a href="{% url 'update-post' f.id %}">
          {% endfor %}
           <button class="wrap_button" >Delete</button>
          </a>
        </div></td>
  </tbody>
```

urls.py
path('update/<step_one>', views.Step1_Form_Update, name='update-post'),